# Correct way to pass a struct to pthread within a for loop

Tags: c++, multithreading, struct, pthreads

**1. Question:** I need to pass a struct containing two integers to a pthread_create call.

This is within a for loop that calculates the values of the struct. Ideally I would like each thread to call the updatePlates() with a different struct.

**2. Problem:** I create the structs {1,2},{3,4},{5,6} but by the time the thread begins working they all have the value {5,6}. It was my *incorrect* understanding that `Tuple t;` is a new temporary variable each loop iteration. But my debug statement `cout<< "t: " << &t << endl;` reveals them to have the same memory address every loop.

**3. Real Question:** What is the correct way to create a 'new' struct and pass it to each thread with unique un-shared values?

```
pthread_t updateThreads[THREADS];
for(size_t i = 0; i < THREADS; ++i)
{
    Tuple t;
    t.start = 1 + (i * increment);
    t.end = t.start + increment -1;
    // Debug Statements //
    cout << "start: " << t.start <<endl;
    cout << "end:   " << t.end <<endl;
    cout << "t:     " << &t <<endl;
    // End Debug //
    returnCode = pthread_create(&updateThreads[i], NULL, updatePlates, (void *)&t);
}
for(size_t i = 0; i < THREADS; ++i)
{
    pthread_join(updateThreads[i], NULL);
}
```

Comment: Similar question with a potential answer.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2576558/pthread-with-unique-struct-as-parameter-c?rq=1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Allocate them on the heap

```
Tuple* t = new Tuple;
```

assign the values

```
t->start = 1 + (i * increment);
t->end = t->start + increment -1;
```

pass to `pthread_create`

```
returnCode = pthread_create(&updateThreads[i], NULL, updatePlates, (void *)t);
```

Then in `updatePlates` free the Tuple.

```
void* updatePlates(void* data)
{
    Tuple* t = (Tuple*)data;

    // do stuff

    delete t;
    return NULL;
}
```

Alternatively as you know how many threads you have, you could define an array of `Tuple`s and pass the index into the array to the `pthread_create` call. But be sure that array stays in scope for the lifetime of the thread function.